# Declare the length of a MSSQL output parameter called from C#

Tags: c#, sqlcommand, sqlparameter

I have a mssql store procedure with two parameters input, output.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Test1
        @Pi_Action          INT,
        @Pv_ErrorMessage    VARCHAR(250)    OUTPUT
```

I am executing this procedure from my application in this way.

```
DbManager dbManager = new DbManager();
dbManager.ProcName = "SP_Test1";
dbManager.addParam("@Pi_Action", SqlDbType.Int, ParameterDirection.Input, 3);
dbManager.addParam("@Pv_ErrorMessage", SqlDbType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Output, null);
        bool resultado = dbManager.executeProc();
```

I have a class called DbManager with two methods.

```
    public void addParam(string paramName, SqlDbType paramType, ParameterDirection paramDirection, object paramValue)
    {
      parametros.Add(new Parametro(paramName, paramType, paramDirection, paramValue));
    }

    public bool executeProc()
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
           SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
           sqlComm.Connection = sqlConnection;
           sqlComm.CommandText = ProcName;
           sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

           SqlParameter sqlPar = null;
           foreach(Parametro parametro in parametros)
           {
              sqlPar = new SqlParameter();
              sqlPar.ParameterName = parametro.paramName;
              sqlPar.SqlDbType = parametro.paramType;
              sqlPar.Direction = parametro.paramDirection;
              sqlPar.Value = parametro.paramValue;
              //sqlPar.Size = 300;
              sqlComm.Parameters.Add(sqlPar);
           }
           sqlConnection.Open();
           sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

           String parVal = (String)sqlComando.Parameters["@Pv_ErrorMessage"].Value;

           return true;
         }
```

In the time that I get the value of the output parameter, this returns me only the first letter of the string.
I must always declare the length of the string parameters?
Exists a way I can avoid to declare the length of the string parameters and return me the whole string?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: just out of curiosity, if you pause your application at the String parVal line and queries the content of sqlComando.Parameters["@Pv_ErrorMessage"].Value on your Immediate Window, what's the response? Is it a one-char string as well?

Comment: You'll find some info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759285/ado-net-the-size-property-has-an-invalid-size-of-0) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342954/ado-net-safe-to-specify-1-for-sqlparameter-size-for-all-varchar-parameters)

Comment: As an aside, the SqlCommand creation needs to be added to a using statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

The SqlParameter class supports a Size property that you're not setting.  Create a new overload for your addParam method that accepts the size in addition to the existing info you're passing and then add the following...

```
sqlPar.Size = yourNewMethodParameterName
```